# How to prohibit android navigation bar from appearing after soft keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, keyboard, android-actionbar

I researched and found several attempts to prohibit the navigation bar from displaying when the soft keyboard is on screen... to no avail. But I encountered a side issue as well. I am using the commonly referred method of using "immersive mode" in my base activity's OnResume().

```
    public void HideTheDarnBars()
    {
        View decorView = Window.DecorView;
        var uiOptions = (int)decorView.SystemUiVisibility;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation;
        decorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
    }
```

But this code seems to get "overridden" by the fact that the keyboard disappearing (when the owning activity goes away) happens AFTER the newly started activity's OnResume() is called. This leaves the status/nav bars in play because of the default behavior of the soft keyboard (i.e. keyboard is shown, status/nav bars are shown). What's the best way to handle this? I want the darn bars gone at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it occurred to me to handle it by explicitly removing the soft keyboard  in the owning activity just before is starts my next activity. This seems to allow the setting in OnResume() to hold.
        View view = CurrentFocus;
        if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService (InputMethodService);
                imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow (view.WindowToken, 0);
        }

Hope this saves someone some time. If you have a better way, I'm all ears.